# Yii2 prettyUrl doesn't work

Tags: yii2

i have a problem..
I use yii2 starter kit with prettyUrl enabled.
It works well on my localhost.
But it doesn't work when i upload to my server.

Here's my code...

.httacces

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

base.php

```
...
'components' => [

    'urlManager'=>require(__DIR__.'/_urlManager.php')
],
...
```

_urlManager.php

```
<?php
return [
    'class'=>'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>[
        // url rules
    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ]
];
```

So far, i just disabled `prettyUrl` and it works fine..
Why my prettyUrl doesnt Works anyway??
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check whether the *mod_rewrite* is enabled in your web server. in Apache you should the *AllowOverride* directive should set to *ALL*.

you should see something like this

```
<Directory "/path/to/the/site/directory/">
  Options Indexes 
  FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be a path related problem

try  path indipendent of the O.S. like this

```
...
'components' => [
    'urlManager'=>require(__DIR__.   DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '_urlManager.php')
],
```

...

Answer (score 0):

```
you have wrong syntax at rules inside urlManager, it must be like:


            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',),
```